# VB.Net WPF : Define BitmapImage with Resources

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I'm trying to use a RadDesktopAlert from Telerik and I need to set an Icon to it. 
So, I did this :

```
Dim bi As New BitmapImage
bi.BeginInit()
bi.UriSource = New Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/questions1.png")
bi.EndInit()
alert.Icon = bi
alert.IconColumnWidth = 75
```

But my alert don't have any icon, it sounds like that it can't find the resource... Build action is set to "Resource" for my file.

Can I have help please ?
Thanks !

Comment: Sure that the Icon property accepts a BitmapImage? You may probably create an Image control, set its Source property to the BitmapImage, and use the Image as value for the Icon property.

Comment: No I'm not sure but according to the FAQ, I should use something like this : alert.Icon = New Image() With { _Key .Source = TryCast(Application.Current.FindResource("DesktopAlertIcon"), ImageSource), _Key .Width = 48, _Key .Height = 48 _} But it's not working at all so I don't know what to do :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, provided that the image file is in folder "Resources" in your Visual Studio project, and that its Build Action is set to Resource:

```
Dim bitmap As New BitmapImage(New Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/questions1.png"))
Dim image As New Image() With {.Source = bitmap}
alert.Icon = image
```

Comment: Ahh thank you Clemens, it's working, I just had to replace As New Image() with As New System.Windows.Controls.Image else I have "'New' can't be used in a MustInherit class"

Comment: You should probably remove `System.Drawing` from the list of imported namespaces in your project.